# How to change wrap if long parameter in intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, formatter

it is possible to change limit of wrap if long parameter? Can be even in intellij internal properties.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can change the hard wrap limit here:

[image: hard wrap at]

Comment: it works? I changed it but during code reformating it seems like it is ignored and nothing is changing. 
Ok i understand now. It push it only to new line, but there is no affect on wrap if long. It is totally different parameter from im seeking for.